# MySQL Query with Counts in columns

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables `l & C` which are linked by two fields `l.mID` and `c.mID` the c table holds three types of records `cs, ls, & vs` with my query I need to select all records from l and as part of the query have three columns showing totals for `cs, ls & vs`;

SO far I am using an outer join:

```
SELECT l.*, COUNT(*) FROM l LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.mID = l.mID WHERE l.mID = 2
```

But this just appends one column with a full total any help would be great thanks.

Comment: By _totals_, do you mean `SUM()` for each of those columns?

Comment: It might be useful in this case to show sample data for the tables and to explain what aggregation you are attempting to do.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: As per juergen below this is what I would like to achieve however I am getting multi plicated values 5 is bemiring 25 any reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your count:

```
select
  l.*
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN c.type = 'cs' then 1 END) as cscount
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN c.type = 'ls' then 1 END) as lscount
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN c.type = 'vs' then 1 END) as vscount
from l
left outer join c on c.mID = l.mID
where l.mID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks buddy really helpful and a great solution to my issue :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  l.*
  ,sum(c.type = 'cs') as cscount
  ,sum(c.type = 'ls') as lscount
  ,sum(c.type = 'vs') as vscount
from l
left outer join c on c.mID = l.mID
where l.mID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for this however it seems to multiply the values i.e. 5 becomes 25 any thoughts? I have repeating lines in the l table as it is a view